# Import OpenStreetMap data fails

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, ubuntu, nominatim

I work in project of geocoding so Ii want to import the OpenStreetMap data. I created a database and name it Nominatim and I tried this command:

> sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file morocco-latest.osm.pbf
> --all –osm2pgsql-cache 18000 2>&1 | tee setup.log

It shows me this message:

> CREATE DB
>
> ERROR: database already exists ( pgsql : // @/nominatim)

Now when I delete my database Nominatim it shows this error message:

> ERROR: unable to find /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sq

BTW I installed postgres with all the packages.

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819170/import-openstreetmaps-data-fails

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data) don't say anything about creating the Nominatim database yourself. And *postgis.sql* belongs to the postgis package, try reinstalling it.

Comment: I followed another tutorial that indicate to create a database..So now how can i corresct the second error ? i have that file (postgis.sql) but not in that direction

Answer (score 2):

The main problem seams to be that your configuration is incorrect.

you have to set the correct postgre and postgis version you installed in `settings/local.php`:

```
<?php
   @define('CONST_Postgresql_Version', '9.3');
   @define('CONST_Postgis_Version', '2.1');
```

Your error line shows, how nominatim tries to use the setup postgre 9.3 in combination with postgis 1.5. This combination isn't supported: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS

you should install postgis 2.1 for postgre 9.3

Answer (score 1):

just change the database name in the following location

```
Nominatim/settings/
```

Edit the database name in this file settings.php.

```
@define('CONST_Database_DSN', 'pgsql://@/nominatim');
```

change with your database name

```
@define('CONST_Database_DSN', 'pgsql://@/nominatimMorocco');
```

If you change your database name here than you also need to change following nominatim installation command.

```
./utils/specialphrases.php --countries > specialphrases_countries.sql
 psql -d nominatimMorocco -f specialphrases_countries.sql

./utils/specialphrases.php --wiki-import > specialphrases.sql
 psql -d nominatimMorocco -f specialphrases.sql
```